# Retrieve friend list facebook SDK 4.0 (id,name,score..) of the same app

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm looking for retrieve all of the friends who use the same app (PHP SDK 4.), with the uid,username, and score

I have this permission for my app:

('email', 'user_about_me', 'user_friends', 'publish_actions',
'user_games_activity')

now, I'm working with this script that retrive just the uid of the user who use the same app:

```
$me = (new \Facebook\FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/friends'))->execute()->getGraphObject(\Facebook\GraphUser::className());

$result = $me->asArray();

// Get user's friends

$friends = $result['data'];

// Converting classes to array

foreach ($friends as $key => $value) {
    $friends[$key] = (array)$value;
     echo $friends[0]['id']; //show the id of the user 0
    echo "|";       
}
```

**and I have a problem just for check all of the friends, I try to change this script, but I can't get all friends, but just the first one... [0]**

now, I search a lot about this topic... but I find just for the old SDK, with a new, what I should do to retrive the uid,username and score of the same app? like this:

```
         echo $friends[0]['id']; //show the id of the user 0
        echo "|";   
         echo $friends[0]['name']; //show the name of the user 0
        echo "|";   
         echo $friends[0]['score']; //show the score of the user 0
        echo "|";
```

[number_uid0] | [nameusername0] | [score0] | [number_uid1] | [nameusername1] | [score1] etc....

**Thank you very much :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can't get ALL friends anymore, only those which also use your app. And all `friends_*` permissions have been removed, so you can't simply retrieve your friends' scores...

But have a look here to find a solution to (what I think is) your problem:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores#read-many-scores

> You can read the set of scores for a player and their friends by issuing an HTTP GET request to `/APP_ID/scores` with the user access_token for that app. The user_friends permission is required in order to view friends' scores. This returns a list of scores for a player and friends who have authorized the app. The list is sorted by descending score value, so it returns friends with the highest scores first. You can use this call to generate a leader board for a player and friends.

Comment: With this script I can just return the id and the name of the first friend in array [0] (2 times, because this accuount has 2 friends who use the same app) , my app is a game and I have other value saved in my database... I need to see what friends use the same app to load all the data I need in my database... I don't want to see all friends....so, I have to change a session to determinate the list who use the same app? I'm new with the sdk of facebook, I try to find something on google but nothing appear...just old sdk... thank you very much for the reply

Comment: Your code says otherwise! As I said, you can't access the `scores` edge for all friends because this is deprecated. Just use `/APP_ID/scores` as I described in my answer.

Comment: I know (now :D ), '/me/friends' , so, I'm asking to see just the friends who use the same app, A lot of game show a list of the friends who use the app to share something, like coins...etc I don't have any idea how to ask the request of the friendlist who use the same app, I'm looking this on web for 2 days, and I find just old sdk or in javascript, do you know what is the correct way? the score is an addittion, for me the important is to get the friendlist who use my app in array... thank you very much